# Can QTP select object by ANY property?

Tags: automation, qtp

I would like to know whether the QTP is able to select object of given type by any propety that it can see (when using the ObjectSpy). I assume it cannot, but needs to make sure.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume incorrectly, any property that shows up in the spy can be used for object identification. 
It may not be a good idea to use some of the properties (`abs_x` springs to mind) but all should work (AFAIK).